# How to pass value when calling contract function?

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

Currently in Truffle I'm passing in value manually, but how do I make this value something I require. For example when I want to make a transaction on MetaMask, there's a transaction that appears requesting x value and I approve it. How would I request value from the user? I want to deploy and test this contract on Rinkeby.

```
TokenSaleContract.at(this.props.address)
        .then(instance => {
            contractInstance = instance;
            contractInstance.buyToken(2, {value: 507087936329796580})
            return c.numberOfTokensFromAddress('0x...')
        })
        .then(numberOfTokens => {
            console.log(`You (0x...) now have ${numberOfTokens}`);
        })
```

Comment: When you say "in Truffle", do you mean you are using Truffle console, right?

Comment: I mean I'm using truffle-contract

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like `readline-sync` to get user input ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync)):

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

// Wait for user's response. 
var userName = readlineSync.question('May I have your name? ');
console.log('Hi ' + userName + '!');
```

**Note:** Do not forget to install the package first, for example `yarn add readline-sync`.

Comment: I'm trying to not require user to input the data, but rather have the value amount sent to the user

Comment: What 'value' are you referring to? You can send ether using `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.

Comment: I'm talking about this line `contractInstance.buyToken(2, {value: 507087936329796580}` I want to have the value passed to the buyer